# select only numbers from list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pandas, numpy

I have a list as follow:

```
listing = ["some string", 0.235, -56.335, -0.889]
```

I'm trying:

```
z = np.asarray(listing, dtype='float32')
```

but this would give an error. So I would like to take only the floats so listing will become:

```
listing = [0.235, -56.335, -0.889]
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

```
listing = ["some string", 0.235, -56.335, -0.889]
num_only = []
for item in listing:
    if isinstance(item, int) or isinstance(item, float):
        num_only.append(item)
```

Or better:

```
numbers_only = [num for num in listing if isinstance(num, (int, float))]
```

Comment: Use `isinstance(item, (float, int))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
np.asarray([num for num in listing if isinstance(num, float)])
```